# column-count property is not working properly in safari and firefox

Tags: html, css, column-count

We are developing a dashboard which is having multiple divs and we are trying to stack a set of divs in the left and a set of divs in the 
right,basically stacking divs in the form of two columns in the main-container-Div.The main div is assigend with a property called column-count=2 and things are working absolutely fine
in Chrome.But when we are testing this on safari and firefox,the column-count is not functioning properly because of which the child divs are not getting splitted in two columns dynamically.What could be the reson behind this issue? any help on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is it possible for you to show your code? it helps people understand your problem

Comment: We have changed the approach for solving this issue(FlexBox).Now the issue has resolved.